# Chromium Install + Executable Path on Heroku (Puppeteer)

Tags: web-scraping, heroku, puppeteer

I have uploaded my Puppeteer script to Heroku but I do not know how to specify the executable path for chrome.exe. I am able to do this easily on my local machine like so:

`executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files\\Chromium\\Application\\chrome.exe'`

But I do not know how to get around this error on my Heroku dyno:

Error: An `executablePath` or `channel` must be specified for `puppeteer-core`

Please feel free to provide any input as I am brand new to programming and want to learn as much as possible.

I have downloaded the puppeteer buildpack. Chromium is installed. I just want to know how to specify the executable path.

Answer (score 0):

Puppeteer downloads and uses a version of Chromium By default. so no need to specify the path.
But if you want to use a different/specific version of Chrome then you can add

```
{executablePath: '/path/to/Chrome'}
```

You are using Heroku So add `https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack` to your buildpacks

Read This Article for more info:
https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/jontewks/puppeteer